# What's stopping Seth entering the elevator?

Tags: plot-explanation, city-of-angels

In **[City of Angels](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120632/)**, In this scene Seth suddenly stops following Maggie into the elevator.

[image]

What's stopping Seth entering the elevator?

Comment: I'm not sure anything is stopping him, but considering he's an angel that can move at the speed of thought he probably saw little reason to stand in a metal box.

Answer (score 1):

### Nothing

He doesn't *exactly* stop...in fact the doors close very quickly in his face...but he could have "transported" himself into the elevator if he wanted.

Instead he "transports" to her destination floor and is waiting for her to come out a few seconds later.